# How to get an array of file names

Tags: bash

I need a script for build an array with the names of files in a folder. For example in the `folder1` I have 4 files, so the array must have in position 0,1,2,3 the names of these 4 files. I've found this script:

```
declare -a FILELIST
for f in *; do
     FILELIST[${#FILELIST[@]}+1]=$(echo "$f");
done

echo ${FILELIST[@]}
```

but I'm new to `bash` and I don't understand the meaning behind these commands.